# Push Notification icon in Settings

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I've got an app that uses Apple's Push Notification Service. I'm registered, and receive the notifications just fine. However, when I go into the Settings -> Notifications area, my app is listed, but there's no icon visible. Is there a flag, or a special PNG I need to include in my bundle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, stupid mistake. The info.plist icon field was empty. By default, the OS still looks for an icon.png file for Springboard, but doesn't use the same trick for the Notification settings.